# Submit validation in anjularjs

Tags: angularjs

Let say I have the following codes:-

```
    <form name="table" ng-submit="createtable()">
        <input type="number" ng-model="tab.num" required></input>{{win.numR}}

        <button>Save</button>
    </form>
```

I will be adding number in this order(1,2,3,4,5,6). What I want to achieve is e.g.

I have input 1,2, and then when I input 6 it prevents me from adding the 6 because I need to add the 3, the 4 and the 5 before the 6.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full Plunkr to help you out.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1GK1JjFLoCJQd4K3l6eh?p=preview

I am using ui-validate to simplify. I suggest using this module to simplify your validation code.

```
var application = angular.module("validator", ["ui.validate"]);
application.controller("ValidatorExampleController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.numberStationValidationFn = function(value) {
        if(angular.isUndefined(value)) {
            return true;
        }

        for(var i = 1; i <= value.length; i++) {
            if(value[i - 1] != i) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
     };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-valid` attribute to your `input` and implement a method which will set the input `valid` to either `true` or `false`:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="tab.num" ng-valid="inputIsValid(tab.num)" required>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.inputIsValid = function(str) {
    // check if str is valid and return true or false
}
```